# Compare two time (hh:mm:ss) strings

Tags: javascript

I have two time strings in `hh:mm:ss` format. (eg: `12:40:13` and `20:01:01`.) How can I compare these in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare two time strings in the format HH:MM:SS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/54DmJ/)

I prefer to have date objects, but as pointed out elsewhere, you can just convert to seconds if you want to do simple compares

```
function dateCompare(time1,time2) {
  var t1 = new Date();
  var parts = time1.split(":");
  t1.setHours(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],0);
  var t2 = new Date();
  parts = time2.split(":");
  t2.setHours(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],0);

  // returns 1 if greater, -1 if less and 0 if the same
  if (t1.getTime()>t2.getTime()) return 1;
  if (t1.getTime()<t2.getTime()) return -1;
  return 0;
}

alert(dateCompare("12:40:13","20:01:01"));
```

For seconds:

```
function dateDiff(time1,time2) {
  var t1 = new Date();
  var parts = time1.split(":");
  t1.setHours(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],0);
  var t2 = new Date();
  parts = time2.split(":");
  t2.setHours(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],0);

  return parseInt(Math.abs(t1.getTime()-t2.getTime())/1000);
}
```

Assuming you have 24 hour times and same padding you can do simple string compare

```
 var t1 = "12:40:13", t2= "20:01:01";
 if (t1<t2) {
    console.log(t1," is < ", t2);
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

If "compare" means "see if they are equal", and the two have the same format, why not simply:

```
var time1 = "12:40:13";
var time2 = "20:01:01";

if (time1 == time2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

If you need to get the difference in time, the conversion to a date object is one way (see mplungjan's answer) or you can convert them to a common unit (say seconds) and subtract:

```
function toSeconds(t) {
    var bits = t.split(':');
    return bits[0]*3600 + bits[1]*60 + bits[2]*1;
}

var secs1 = toSeconds(time1);
var secs2 = toSeconds(time2);

// do stuff  - compare, subtract, less than, greater than, whatever
```

Comment: Yeah, I always make date objects - but obviously it is not always necessary

Comment: That's fine, I just wanted to offer a non-date alternative.

Comment: How much fast is this than making a date object?

Comment: @Whitecat—you can write some tests to find out, make sure you test across a good variety of hosts as relative performance likely differs. However, I doubt that the difference in performance is significant and is unlikely to be the determining factor in which method to use unless you have many such operations to perform.

Comment: I have 17 million such operations to preform.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion that I modified from the solution in [this website here](http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?t=67146), hope it helps.

```
function compareTime(time_1, time_2) {
   var s1 = 
       time1.split(":")[0] * 3600 + time1.split(":")[1] * 60 + time1.split(":")[2];
   var s2 = 
       time2.split(":")[0] * 3600 + time2.split(":")[1] * 60 + time1.split(":")[2];
   return Math.abs(s1 - s2); // Gets difference in seconds
}

var time_1 = "12:40:13", time_2 = "20:01:01";
document.write(compareTime(time_1, time_2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take:

```
function compareTimes(timeOne, timeTwo) {           
    if(daterize(timeOne) > daterize(timeTwo)) return 1;
    if(daterize(timeOne) < daterize(timeTwo)) return -1;
    return 0;
}

function daterize(time) {
    return Date.parse("Thu, 01 Jan 1970 " + time + " GMT");
}
```

You may also want to take a look at the [MDN Javascript docs for Dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). 
Javascript comes with a lot of gotchas, like Date.month going from 0-11.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date.parse('01/01/2011 10:20:45') > Date.parse('01/01/2011 5:10:10')

 The 1st January is an arbitrary date, doesn't mean anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var time1 = "09:30";
var time2 = "15:30";

var time1InMinutesForTime1 = getTimeAsNumberOfMinutes(time1);
var time1InMinutesForTime2 = getTimeAsNumberOfMinutes(time2);

var time1IsBeforeTime2 = time1InMinutesForTime1 < time1InMinutesForTime2;

function getTimeAsNumberOfMinutes(time) {
    var timeParts = time.split(":");

    var timeInMinutes = (timeParts[0] * 60) + timeParts[1];

    return Number(timeInMinutes);
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive and explain the code?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 time string in **24 hour format**:

```
const string1 = new Date().toLocaleTimeString({ hour12: false }); 
const string2 = new Date().toLocaleTimeString({ hour12: false });
```

you can simply compare these two strings:

```
string1 < string2 ? 'string1 < string2' : 'string1 > string2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the times are in the same time zone, simply compare the strings.

This evaluates to `true`:

```
"12:40:13" < "20:01:01"
```

Note that the items being compared must use the same hh:mm:ss format (for example, `"05:00:00" < "4:00:00"` evaluates to `true`, which is not what you want).

Comment: Accepted answer already suggested that.