# compare two times to return boolean value as true or false

Tags: javascript

I have time in the format "hh:mm" in 24 hr format. Now how to compare two times such that it returns the boolean value . And if both the times is same in hours then should compare minutes and return either true or false. Meaning t1="15:30" and t2="15:40" should return false if checking whether t1> t2 using javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632808/compare-two-time-hhmmss-strings . Next time search before posting. :)

Comment: Native JS Date objects can be compared using `>`, `==` and `<`

Comment: 24 hour format has the advantage that if you have them in string form, they'll compare correctly by just the regular string comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
return t1==t2
```

is enough for the above question

Answer (score 0):

Dates that are formatted `HH:mm` (ie always 2 digit hours) with 24 hours time will compare correctly as strings without converting them;

```
var t1 = "15:30";
var t2 = "15:40";

console.log(t1 < t2);
console.log(t1 == t2);
console.log(t1 > t2);

> true
> false
> false
```

Comment: and if it is in 12 hr format that ia 10:30 AM , does that comparison work

Comment: @user13763 No, only 24 hour format as stated in the question.