# How can i convert a time (12:30 am) into timestamp using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me how to that? I would like to compare 2 times and find out which one is greater? like 12:30 pm and 5:30 pm

Comment: check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss

Answer (score 1):

Use Date().parse()

```
Date.parse('24/09/2011 15:21:41')
```

Comment: @sam `Date.parse()` should work with a lot of different formats. Have you actually tried this yet?

Answer (score 1):

If the input is always similar as mentioned at the question:

```
var time1 = "12:30 pm";
var time2 = "5:30pm";
var time1_higher_than_time2 = compareTime(time1, time2);
if(time1_higher_than_time2) alert("Time1 is higher than time 2");
else alert("Time1 is not higher than time 2. "); /* Time1 <= time2*/

/*Illustrative code. Returns true if time1 is greater than time2*/
function compareTime(time1, time2){
    var re = /^([012]?\d):([0-6]?\d)\s*(a|p)m$/i;
    time1 = time1.match(re);
    time2 = time2.match(re);
    if(time1 && time2){
        var is_pm1 = /p/i.test(time1[3]) ? 12 : 0;
        var hour1 = (time1[1]*1 + is_pm1) % 12;
        var is_pm2 = /p/i.test(time2[3]) ? 12 : 0;
        var hour2 = (time2[1]*1 + is_pm2) % 12;
        if(hour1 != hour2) return hour1 > hour2;

        var minute1 = time1[2]*1;
        var minute2 = time2[2]*1;
        return minute1 > minute2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the times into `javascript dates`, call `getTime()` on the dates to return the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970.

Compare the `getTime()` returned values on each date to determine which is greater.

For 12 Hour format the code below will work.

```
var date1 = new Date('Sat Sep 24 2011 12:30:00 PM').getTime(); //12:30 pm
var date2 = new Date('Sat Sep 24 2011 5:30:00 PM').getTime(); //5:30 pm

if(date1 > date2) {
    alert('date1 is greater');
} else if(date2 > date1) {
    alert('date2 is greater');
} else {
    alert('dates are equal');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just parse it in 12H time and compared them.
Running example in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UykRB/)

```
var date1 = Date.parse('01/01/2001 12:30 PM');
var date2 = Date.parse('01/01/2001 5:30 PM');

console.log(date1 > date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below link-
http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/162449-Time-Comparison-Javascript.aspx

You can test out your javascript online here -
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var start = "01:00 PM";
   var end = "11:00 AM";
   var dtStart = new Date("1/1/2007 " + start);
   var dtEnd = new Date("1/1/2007 " + end);
   var difference_in_milliseconds = dtEnd - dtStart;

   if (difference_in_milliseconds < 0)
   {
      alert("End date is before start date!");
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```