# jQuery datetimepicker validation -  Timepicker UI 

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am building a jQuery plugin to create subtitles on videos and I using the library **[Timepicker UI](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)** to define the begin and end, that each subtitle start and end.

I am using an **input** tag:

```
<input class="HoursStart hasDatepicker valid" type="text"
 value="0" name="HoursStart">
```

And the **javascript** code using the format (**hh:mm:ss**):

```
$('.HoursStart ').timepicker(
{
    showSecond: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss'
});
```

The problems are with the validation:

1. Is there a way to just allow the input to accept the format
   **hh:mm:ss** (just numbers on the correct range) ?
2. Is there a way to make the comparisons between two inputs (something like 
   **if (12:21:12 > 11:31:12)**)?

I really appreciate your help to solve this validation problems. If there is another jQuery library that makes what I want, is not a problem for me to change to other jQuery library.

Comment: Does anyone already found any solution for this question? I'm in need of this validation too! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/billpull/c8fQ4/)** for testing the `regex` and comparing the time strings:

```
$(function () {
   var timeRegex = new RegExp('([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})');
    var originalTime = "00:10:20";

    $('#submit').click(function(){
       var time = $.trim($('#time').val());
       var isTime = timeRegex.test(time);
       var greater = time > originalTime;
        var testString = "Is correct format: "+isTime +", is greater:" + greater;
       window.alert(testString); 
    });
});
```

more discussion on comparing that time format 
[How can I compare two time strings in the format HH:MM:SS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss)

Answer (score 0):

Following time picker could be useful as it requires only jquery and no need to include any library.
http://jsfiddle.net/W4wwv/3/

HTML:

```
    <span class="timepicker">
    <input type="text" name="hh" class="hh" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="HH">:
    <input type="text" name="mm" class="mm" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="MM">:
    <input type="text" name="ss" class="ss" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="SS">
    </span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="h"></div>
    <div id="m"></div>
    <div id="s"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .timepicker{
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    display:block;
    height:23px;
    width:98px;
    }
    .timepicker input{
    width:25px;
    border:0px;
    margin-bottom:1px !important;
    maxlength:2
    }
```

JS:

```
    var validateNumber = function(n, min, max){

            if(n > max)return max;
            else if(n < min)return min;
            return n;
    };

    var validateAfterChange = function(n , min){

            var numReg = /^[0-9]{1,2}$/;

            if(!numReg.test(n))                     
            return "00";
            if(n.length <= 1) return "0"+n;
            return n;
    }

    $(".hh")
    .on("keyup", function(){
        var v = validateNumber($(this).val(), 0, 23);
    $(this).val(v);
    $("#h").html($(this).val());
    })
    .on("change", function(){
            var v = validateAfterChange($(this).val(), 0);
            $(this).val(v);
    });


    $(".mm")
    .on("keyup", function(){
            var v = validateNumber($(this).val(), 0, 60);
            $(this).val(v);
            $("#m").html($(this).val());
    }).on("change", function(){
        var v = validateAfterChange($(this).val(), 0);
            $(this).val(v);
    });

    $(".ss")
.on("keyup", function(){
        var v = validateNumber($(this).val(), 0, 60);
    $(this).val(v);
    $("#m").html($(this).val());
}).on("change", function(){
        var v = validateAfterChange($(this).val(), 0);
    $(this).val(v);
    });
```