# How to get the difference between two times with format(hr:min:sec)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 2 textbox for the user to enter times. How to get the difference between two times with format(hr:min:sec)

Comment: what have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss

Answer (score -1):

I think you will get the idea from that links.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-HP010070468.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-HP003056108.aspx

Comment: Question is tagged javascript/jquery.

Comment: Hi Rick, Welcome to StackOverflow. Monica asked how to accomplish this using JavaScript (see the tags). Please consider removing your answer or changing it to something that might help Monica.