# How to compare now time and a given time value in angular 5

Tags: javascript, ionic3, angular5

I am working on a project using angular 5, and i want to compare to time values, one being the now time, and the other being the value i want to compare the now time with, so that if a particular condition is true, i can enable a button i disable, but i don't know how to go through with the logic involve, i try to do this but is not working:

```
now: any = Date.now();


 compareTime = '12:00:00pm'
```

And one hour after the `now` time  is equal to `compareTime`, the button is disable again, then till the next day at noon, the button will be enable for an hour again, from `12:00:00pm` to `01:00:00pm`, and i have not been able to reach any document that will help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare time in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004950/how-to-compare-time-in-javascript)