# Javascript Time Function Issues

Tags: javascript

Having trouble taking a time entered into a text box in html5 and writing a javascript function that will make sure the time entered is no less than 30 minutes from the present time. Mainly how to get the current date is my biggest concern. Would it be as simple as a date.now() and then adding 30 minutes to that?

Comment: If you're willing to use a library please consider: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: What do you mean you can't find anything on time or date? There is a lot of help out there for time and date using JavaScript. Just look at w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: If you're willing to find something consider [Google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20date%20time)

Comment: What about Date.parse() to parse the input string into a date object and then comparing to the current time?  Check this existing post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss

Comment: "Can't find anything on time or date functions for javascript". I find that hard to believe. What did you search for? I'll suggest [MDN as a good source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Trying not to use libraries and more of less how to get the current date and then add 30 minutes to it to verify.

Comment: Useless? Well if that Google query wasn't what you were looking for I'm not sure you'll find much help here.

Comment: That google query, which I've been searching through all afternoon, showed me simply how to get the current date. I get that. What I don't get is to take a string time entered by the user and to treat that string as a time and compare it to 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used moment.js for a project..  Has some really nice Time methods...

```
//// get today right now
var now = ( new Date() );
/// to see methods that a javascript date object contains try listing them
console.log( Object.keys(  now  )  );
```

give moment.js a google,  makes finding differences between 2 dates easy..

Comment: Trying not to use any libraries but thank you. I feel like it should be a lot simpler than its planning out to be. I've been using the first line of code to get the current date. Trying to transfer a a string input and comparing it to current date to make sure its no less than 30 minutes after the current date.