# How to compare time in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I have two variable

```
1)$scope.priviuosLevelCutoffTime like 12:00
2)data.cutOffTime(form JSON) like 13:00
```

I want to compare whether these two times are equal or greater by using angular js, can anyone explain to me? How can I compare?

Comment: Same as you would with basic JS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss

Comment: Use Moment.js library : http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular does not provide any such method. You would have to use native JS date objects.

```
var date1 = Date.parse('01/01/1970 ' + $scope.priviuosLevelCutoffTime+':00')
var date1 = Date.parse('01/01/1970 ' + data.cutOffTime+':00')
//date1>date2
```

You can put the variables into `$scope` if you want to use them in the template.

Answer (score 2):

Angular has not providr utilities for Date Time

You can use angular moment instead :- https://github.com/urish/angular-moment