# JavaScript value comparison bug

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this problem that I don't know how to fix. I have this piece of code in JavaScript. There are two console logs that writes variable to console that I later compare if one is bigger than other. Problem is that JavaScript wrongly compare them in `if(alarmArray[i].ExtId < offsetTime)` even `if alarmArray[i].ExtId = 11:42:35`  and  `offsetTime = 11:42:7`  the condition is still meet and IF will return `true`. Is this some kind of JavaScript bug?

```
for (var i = alarmArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        console.log(alarmArray[i].ExtId);    //writes 11:42:37
        console.log(offsetTime);             //writes 11:42:7
        if (alarmArray[i].ExtId < offsetTime) {  
            console.log(alarmArray[i]);  
            alarmArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe if we had a clue what `alarmArray` or `offsetTime` contained we could be more helpful.

Comment: Well its in the text and next to that code.  alarmArray[i].ExtId = 11:42:35 and offsetTime = 11:42:7 its time comparing.There are two console logs that writes those compared values.

Comment: are those string values? if yes this is the expected behaviour....

Comment: Look here: [How can I compare two time strings in the format HH:MM:SS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss)

Comment: Loops take time to run. You're running a loop and expecting the same time to output if I had to guess, but you're coming up fractions offset.

Comment: Yes those are strings but if this is expected shouldnt "11:42:35" still be bigger than "11:42:7"?

Comment: in string comparison "11:42:3" + any char is lower than "11:42:7", you need to convert the values to date or number to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare two strings directly if you use **the correct format**:

```
HH:MM:SS < HH:MM:SS
```

But you are trying to compare `HH:MM:SS < HH:MM:S` which is a wrong format.

Actually, I think the best answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212411/3648578

Answer (score 0):

Ok its fixed. I forgot add zero to seconds and minutes in function that formate my time.`function formatTime(item) {
        var hour = item.getHours(), min = item.getMinutes(), sec = item.getSeconds();
        if (sec <= 9) sec = "0" + sec;
        if (min <= 9) min = "0" + min;
        var time = "" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + "";
        return time;
    }`

if (sec <= 9) sec = "0" + sec;  if (min <= 9) min = "0" + min;   was missing in my code