# How to compare times don't using without if else

Tags: javascript

I have for example that time "15:00:00" and "15:30:00"

firstly i do split and cast to Integer

```
const hour = Number(this.time.split(':')[0]);
const minutes = Number(this.time.split(':')[1]);
```

and later i using for example `if(hour > hour1) { .... }`

I know that this method is not optimal is some tips to compare time?

Comment: how are you comparing time of two different date, like, let say, one is `23:00:00 ` and the other one is `01:00:00` of the next day

Comment: you can convert the time string to a common format (like seconds) and then compare them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two time strings in the format HH:MM:SS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss)

Comment: `'15:00:00' > '15:30:00'`

Comment: Plz check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss

Answer (score 1):

If you can use libs, I'd recommend moment.js. It makes it easy to work with datetimes.

For example:

```js
var first = moment('15:00:00', 'hh:mm:ss');
var second = moment('15:30:00', 'hh:mm:ss');
console.log(first.isAfter(second));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```