# Comparing time difference in two strings (JS)

Tags: javascript

[Couldn't find help in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss)

I got 2 strings. For example :

```
let str1 = '11:00'
let str2 = '08:00'
```

I need to be able to get the hours difference between - in this example str1-str2=3.

I tried to `parseInt()` but it won't actually transform the whole string to numbers.
Any ides?

Comment: One way to do it is explained in the post you linked - pad your string with an arbitrary date and seconds and process it as a date object - then you'll be able to calculate the hours difference.

Comment: Create two dates `var date1 = new Date('11:00 01-01-2020');`, then `var date2 = new Date('8:00 01-01-2020');` and take the difference `var diff = date1.getHours() - date2.getHours();` - in case you want to plug values in do `var date1 = new Date('${str1} - 01-01-2020');` - replace ' with back tick of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` by ":".
"regroup" `[0]` as hours and `[1]` as minutes (divide by 60).
Do the difference.
Note: Can give negative hours and long fraction.
Note: Fraction in minute format was not requested, but can be done.
Note: Fraction in fixed number of decimals was not requested, but can be done.

```js
var str1 = "11:00";
var str2 = "08:00";

function hourMinuteStringToHourNumber(str) {
  var time = str.split(":");
  return +time[0]+time[1]/60;
};

function logDifference(timeStr1, timeStr2) {
  var time1=hourMinuteStringToHourNumber(timeStr1);
  var time2=hourMinuteStringToHourNumber(timeStr2);
  var diff=time1-time2;
  console.log(timeStr1+" - "+timeStr2+" = "+diff);
};

logDifference(str1, str2);

logDifference("18:45", "10:15");
logDifference("14:40", "10:20");
logDifference("11:23", "16:47");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```