# how to check if current utc time is between two time using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am getting the current utc time as let time = moment.utc()
and I need to check if this time is between '04:30:00' and '16:30:00' both time in utc. But I cannot format the time as moment.isBetween doesn't accept string. How to check if my current time is between those two values ?

Comment: get the time from `time` in format `hh:mm:ss` ... then do a string comparison .. since, for example, `"09:30:00" > "04:30:00"` and `< "16:30:00"` - that would be the simplest solution in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

this solution may help you
[How can I compare two time strings in the format HH:MM:SS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss)

You just need to convert this utc time to simple time than compare them.
convert utc : `moment().utc().format('hh:mm:ss')`